# Shuffle array of N letters and take M of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random

I have an X array of objects `"letter":"frequency"` and i'm trying to build a new Y array from the previous one made of frequency-times letters (for each present in X ary). Then my purpose is to shuffle Y ary and take just the z-first elements from that. `n` is an argument passed to the function

```
exports.listLetters = (n) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM letters';
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        if (rows == undefined) {
            resolve({ error: "Errors with retrieving letters. " })
        } else {

            const letters = rows.map((e) => ({ letter: e.letter, frequency: e.frequency }));const letters = rows.map((e) => ({ letter: e.letter, frequency: e.frequency }));
            let freqLetters = [];
            for (let letter in letters) {
                for (let i = 0; i <= letter.frequency * 100; i++) {
                    freqLetters.push(letter);
                }
            };

            shuffleArray(freqLetters);
            freqLetters.slice(0, n);

            resolve(freqLetters);
```

Why this algorithm doesn't work?
Shuffle function is:

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
}
```

Comment: Could you share an example of the test data "rows"?

Comment: Just post an answer,. Check if it works, but since I doesn't have your code before, it may a little different.

Comment: This line `const letters = rows.map((e) => ({ letter: e.letter, frequency: e.frequency }));const letters = rows.map((e) => ({ letter: e.letter, frequency: e.frequency }));` should throw an error. You can't define the same `const` twice in the same scope. And what's the purpose of this mapping anyway? Then, get updated on how [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) works. Did you check what values the variables `letter` and `letter.frequency` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem that make your code doesn't work is you can't directly use `for in` to loop through the array contains array. You doesn't define the rows and letter so I create one for showing purpose.

**You missed the property name**, I would suugest you to use `forEach` as an alternative option.

Also, slice doesn't change on the original array, it creates a copy, so you should define another array.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end

```js
let rows = [{
    letter: 'word',
    frequency: 5
  },
  {
    letter: 'yes',
    frequency: 4
  },
  {
    letter: 'no',
    frequency: 3
  }
]
let n = 10
const letters = rows.map((e) => ({
  letter: e.letter,
  frequency: e.frequency
}));

let freqLetters = [];

letters.forEach(function(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.frequency * 100; i++)
    freqLetters.push(arr.letter);


})

shuffleArray(freqLetters);
let finalarray = freqLetters.slice(0, n)
console.log(finalarray)
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}
```